# Woocommerce Product Variation override get_stock_quantity - accessing parent object

Tags: woocommerce

I want to override the get_stock_quantity for a specific product to allow for a single variant to not ever run out of stock ( its virtual so no stock, but you can't switch off stock management for a single variant )

I can get my method called

```
function test_get_digital_stock_quantity( $value) {
    echo "<br/>STOCK!<br/>";
    var_dump($value);
    return $value;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_get_stock_quantity', 'test_get_digital_stock_quantity',10,1);
```

Which is great, however I only want to do it for specific variations not all. So I need to access the thing this was called on. However the function only seems to take a single parameter even though the calling code suggests its passing $this.

```
$value = apply_filters( $this->get_hook_prefix() . $prop, $value, $this );
```

So the question is, how do I get the thing that the get_prop was called on in the function that I have written. I need to be able to access the SKU in order to make the decision about the stock quantity to return...

Answer (score 0):

Just realised the add_filter required a 2 not a 1 for it to be passed.

add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_get_stock_quantity', 'test_get_digital_stock_quantity',10,2)